# Failed to get the values of a column from a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script using the requests module to scrape content from this [webpage](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL). I'm willing to get the content revealed upon pressing the `Income Statement` and then `annual` tab. I could fetch them using the requests module and the BeautifulSoup library if a few fields, as in `Operating Revenue` within `Total Revenue` were not generated dynamically.

So, I've used the following method to fetch them. Now, the only problem that I can't solve is getting the values under the `TTM` column. The `TTM` values are within the keys, starting with `trailing` in the JSON content. I can't integrate them accordingly so that the results get printed in this manner:

```
Breakdown TTM 9/29/2023 6/29/2023
```

This is what I've tried with:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/AAPL'

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Origin': 'https://finance.yahoo.com',
    'Referer': 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL',
}

params = {
    'lang': 'en-US',
    'region': 'US',
    'symbol': 'AAPL',
    'padTimeSeries': 'true',
    'type': 'annualTaxEffectOfUnusualItems,trailingTaxEffectOfUnusualItems,annualTaxRateForCalcs,trailingTaxRateForCalcs,annualNormalizedEBITDA,trailingNormalizedEBITDA,annualNormalizedDilutedEPS,trailingNormalizedDilutedEPS,annualNormalizedBasicEPS,trailingNormalizedBasicEPS,annualTotalUnusualItems,trailingTotalUnusualItems,annualTotalUnusualItemsExcludingGoodwill,trailingTotalUnusualItemsExcludingGoodwill,annualNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest,trailingNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest,annualReconciledDepreciation,trailingReconciledDepreciation,annualReconciledCostOfRevenue,trailingReconciledCostOfRevenue,annualEBITDA,trailingEBITDA,annualEBIT,trailingEBIT,annualNetInterestIncome,trailingNetInterestIncome,annualInterestExpense,trailingInterestExpense,annualInterestIncome,trailingInterestIncome,annualContinuingAndDiscontinuedDilutedEPS,trailingContinuingAndDiscontinuedDilutedEPS,annualContinuingAndDiscontinuedBasicEPS,trailingContinuingAndDiscontinuedBasicEPS,annualNormalizedIncome,trailingNormalizedIncome,annualNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation,trailingNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation,annualTotalExpenses,trailingTotalExpenses,annualRentExpenseSupplemental,trailingRentExpenseSupplemental,annualReportedNormalizedDilutedEPS,trailingReportedNormalizedDilutedEPS,annualReportedNormalizedBasicEPS,trailingReportedNormalizedBasicEPS,annualTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported,trailingTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported,annualDividendPerShare,trailingDividendPerShare,annualDilutedAverageShares,trailingDilutedAverageShares,annualBasicAverageShares,trailingBasicAverageShares,annualDilutedEPS,trailingDilutedEPS,annualDilutedEPSOtherGainsLosses,trailingDilutedEPSOtherGainsLosses,annualTaxLossCarryforwardDilutedEPS,trailingTaxLossCarryforwardDilutedEPS,annualDilutedAccountingChange,trailingDilutedAccountingChange,annualDilutedExtraordinary,trailingDilutedExtraordinary,annualDilutedDiscontinuousOperations,trailingDilutedDiscontinuousOperations,annualDilutedContinuousOperations,trailingDilutedContinuousOperations,annualBasicEPS,trailingBasicEPS,annualBasicEPSOtherGainsLosses,trailingBasicEPSOtherGainsLosses,annualTaxLossCarryforwardBasicEPS,trailingTaxLossCarryforwardBasicEPS,annualBasicAccountingChange,trailingBasicAccountingChange,annualBasicExtraordinary,trailingBasicExtraordinary,annualBasicDiscontinuousOperations,trailingBasicDiscontinuousOperations,annualBasicContinuousOperations,trailingBasicContinuousOperations,annualDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders,trailingDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders,annualAverageDilutionEarnings,trailingAverageDilutionEarnings,annualNetIncomeCommonStockholders,trailingNetIncomeCommonStockholders,annualOtherunderPreferredStockDividend,trailingOtherunderPreferredStockDividend,annualPreferredStockDividends,trailingPreferredStockDividends,annualNetIncome,trailingNetIncome,annualMinorityInterests,trailingMinorityInterests,annualNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests,trailingNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests,annualNetIncomeFromTaxLossCarryforward,trailingNetIncomeFromTaxLossCarryforward,annualNetIncomeExtraordinary,trailingNetIncomeExtraordinary,annualNetIncomeDiscontinuousOperations,trailingNetIncomeDiscontinuousOperations,annualNetIncomeContinuousOperations,trailingNetIncomeContinuousOperations,annualEarningsFromEquityInterestNetOfTax,trailingEarningsFromEquityInterestNetOfTax,annualTaxProvision,trailingTaxProvision,annualPretaxIncome,trailingPretaxIncome,annualOtherIncomeExpense,trailingOtherIncomeExpense,annualOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses,trailingOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses,annualSpecialIncomeCharges,trailingSpecialIncomeCharges,annualGainOnSaleOfPPE,trailingGainOnSaleOfPPE,annualGainOnSaleOfBusiness,trailingGainOnSaleOfBusiness,annualOtherSpecialCharges,trailingOtherSpecialCharges,annualWriteOff,trailingWriteOff,annualImpairmentOfCapitalAssets,trailingImpairmentOfCapitalAssets,annualRestructuringAndMergernAcquisition,trailingRestructuringAndMergernAcquisition,annualSecuritiesAmortization,trailingSecuritiesAmortization,annualEarningsFromEquityInterest,trailingEarningsFromEquityInterest,annualGainOnSaleOfSecurity,trailingGainOnSaleOfSecurity,annualNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense,trailingNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense,annualTotalOtherFinanceCost,trailingTotalOtherFinanceCost,annualInterestExpenseNonOperating,trailingInterestExpenseNonOperating,annualInterestIncomeNonOperating,trailingInterestIncomeNonOperating,annualOperatingIncome,trailingOperatingIncome,annualOperatingExpense,trailingOperatingExpense,annualOtherOperatingExpenses,trailingOtherOperatingExpenses,annualOtherTaxes,trailingOtherTaxes,annualProvisionForDoubtfulAccounts,trailingProvisionForDoubtfulAccounts,annualDepreciationAmortizationDepletionIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationAmortizationDepletionIncomeStatement,annualDepletionIncomeStatement,trailingDepletionIncomeStatement,annualDepreciationAndAmortizationInIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationAndAmortizationInIncomeStatement,annualAmortization,trailingAmortization,annualAmortizationOfIntangiblesIncomeStatement,trailingAmortizationOfIntangiblesIncomeStatement,annualDepreciationIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationIncomeStatement,annualResearchAndDevelopment,trailingResearchAndDevelopment,annualSellingGeneralAndAdministration,trailingSellingGeneralAndAdministration,annualSellingAndMarketingExpense,trailingSellingAndMarketingExpense,annualGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense,trailingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense,annualOtherGandA,trailingOtherGandA,annualInsuranceAndClaims,trailingInsuranceAndClaims,annualRentAndLandingFees,trailingRentAndLandingFees,annualSalariesAndWages,trailingSalariesAndWages,annualGrossProfit,trailingGrossProfit,annualCostOfRevenue,trailingCostOfRevenue,annualTotalRevenue,trailingTotalRevenue,annualExciseTaxes,trailingExciseTaxes,annualOperatingRevenue,trailingOperatingRevenue',
    'merge': 'false',
    'period1': '493590046',
    'period2': '1705664498',
    'corsDomain': 'finance.yahoo.com',
}

res = requests.get(link,params=params,headers=headers)
for item in res.json()['timeseries']['result']:
    for i,v in item.items():
        if i=="meta" or i=="timestamp": continue
        if i.startswith('annual'):
            title = i.strip('annual')
            try:
                third_val_raw = v[2]['reportedValue']['raw']
                third_val = int(third_val_raw) if third_val_raw.is_integer() else third_val_raw
            except (IndexError,TypeError): third_val = ""
            try:
                fourth_val_raw = v[3]['reportedValue']['raw']
                fourth_val = int(fourth_val_raw) if fourth_val_raw.is_integer() else fourth_val_raw
            except (IndexError,TypeError): fourth_val = ""
            print(title,fourth_val,third_val)
```

Current output (truncated) are like (Missing `TTM` values):

```
NetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest 96995000000 99803000000
TotalOperatingIncomeAsReported 114301000000 119437000000
BasicAverageShares  16215963000
ReconciledDepreciatio 11519000000 11104000000
OperatingExpense 54847000000 51345000000
TotalRevenue 383285000000 394328000000
ResearchAndDevelopment 29915000000 26251000000
InterestExpense 3933000000 2931000000
DilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders 96995000000 99803000000
NetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests 96995000000 99803000000
```

How can I fetch the values under the `TTM` column and print them with other results the script is currently producing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to construct the dataframe from the returned data (with `TTM` column as shown on the page).

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/AAPL"

headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Origin": "https://finance.yahoo.com",
    "Referer": "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL",
}

params = {
    "lang": "en-US",
    "region": "US",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "padTimeSeries": "true",
    "type": "annualTaxEffectOfUnusualItems,trailingTaxEffectOfUnusualItems,annualTaxRateForCalcs,trailingTaxRateForCalcs,annualNormalizedEBITDA,trailingNormalizedEBITDA,annualNormalizedDilutedEPS,trailingNormalizedDilutedEPS,annualNormalizedBasicEPS,trailingNormalizedBasicEPS,annualTotalUnusualItems,trailingTotalUnusualItems,annualTotalUnusualItemsExcludingGoodwill,trailingTotalUnusualItemsExcludingGoodwill,annualNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest,trailingNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest,annualReconciledDepreciation,trailingReconciledDepreciation,annualReconciledCostOfRevenue,trailingReconciledCostOfRevenue,annualEBITDA,trailingEBITDA,annualEBIT,trailingEBIT,annualNetInterestIncome,trailingNetInterestIncome,annualInterestExpense,trailingInterestExpense,annualInterestIncome,trailingInterestIncome,annualContinuingAndDiscontinuedDilutedEPS,trailingContinuingAndDiscontinuedDilutedEPS,annualContinuingAndDiscontinuedBasicEPS,trailingContinuingAndDiscontinuedBasicEPS,annualNormalizedIncome,trailingNormalizedIncome,annualNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation,trailingNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation,annualTotalExpenses,trailingTotalExpenses,annualRentExpenseSupplemental,trailingRentExpenseSupplemental,annualReportedNormalizedDilutedEPS,trailingReportedNormalizedDilutedEPS,annualReportedNormalizedBasicEPS,trailingReportedNormalizedBasicEPS,annualTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported,trailingTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported,annualDividendPerShare,trailingDividendPerShare,annualDilutedAverageShares,trailingDilutedAverageShares,annualBasicAverageShares,trailingBasicAverageShares,annualDilutedEPS,trailingDilutedEPS,annualDilutedEPSOtherGainsLosses,trailingDilutedEPSOtherGainsLosses,annualTaxLossCarryforwardDilutedEPS,trailingTaxLossCarryforwardDilutedEPS,annualDilutedAccountingChange,trailingDilutedAccountingChange,annualDilutedExtraordinary,trailingDilutedExtraordinary,annualDilutedDiscontinuousOperations,trailingDilutedDiscontinuousOperations,annualDilutedContinuousOperations,trailingDilutedContinuousOperations,annualBasicEPS,trailingBasicEPS,annualBasicEPSOtherGainsLosses,trailingBasicEPSOtherGainsLosses,annualTaxLossCarryforwardBasicEPS,trailingTaxLossCarryforwardBasicEPS,annualBasicAccountingChange,trailingBasicAccountingChange,annualBasicExtraordinary,trailingBasicExtraordinary,annualBasicDiscontinuousOperations,trailingBasicDiscontinuousOperations,annualBasicContinuousOperations,trailingBasicContinuousOperations,annualDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders,trailingDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders,annualAverageDilutionEarnings,trailingAverageDilutionEarnings,annualNetIncomeCommonStockholders,trailingNetIncomeCommonStockholders,annualOtherunderPreferredStockDividend,trailingOtherunderPreferredStockDividend,annualPreferredStockDividends,trailingPreferredStockDividends,annualNetIncome,trailingNetIncome,annualMinorityInterests,trailingMinorityInterests,annualNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests,trailingNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests,annualNetIncomeFromTaxLossCarryforward,trailingNetIncomeFromTaxLossCarryforward,annualNetIncomeExtraordinary,trailingNetIncomeExtraordinary,annualNetIncomeDiscontinuousOperations,trailingNetIncomeDiscontinuousOperations,annualNetIncomeContinuousOperations,trailingNetIncomeContinuousOperations,annualEarningsFromEquityInterestNetOfTax,trailingEarningsFromEquityInterestNetOfTax,annualTaxProvision,trailingTaxProvision,annualPretaxIncome,trailingPretaxIncome,annualOtherIncomeExpense,trailingOtherIncomeExpense,annualOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses,trailingOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses,annualSpecialIncomeCharges,trailingSpecialIncomeCharges,annualGainOnSaleOfPPE,trailingGainOnSaleOfPPE,annualGainOnSaleOfBusiness,trailingGainOnSaleOfBusiness,annualOtherSpecialCharges,trailingOtherSpecialCharges,annualWriteOff,trailingWriteOff,annualImpairmentOfCapitalAssets,trailingImpairmentOfCapitalAssets,annualRestructuringAndMergernAcquisition,trailingRestructuringAndMergernAcquisition,annualSecuritiesAmortization,trailingSecuritiesAmortization,annualEarningsFromEquityInterest,trailingEarningsFromEquityInterest,annualGainOnSaleOfSecurity,trailingGainOnSaleOfSecurity,annualNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense,trailingNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense,annualTotalOtherFinanceCost,trailingTotalOtherFinanceCost,annualInterestExpenseNonOperating,trailingInterestExpenseNonOperating,annualInterestIncomeNonOperating,trailingInterestIncomeNonOperating,annualOperatingIncome,trailingOperatingIncome,annualOperatingExpense,trailingOperatingExpense,annualOtherOperatingExpenses,trailingOtherOperatingExpenses,annualOtherTaxes,trailingOtherTaxes,annualProvisionForDoubtfulAccounts,trailingProvisionForDoubtfulAccounts,annualDepreciationAmortizationDepletionIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationAmortizationDepletionIncomeStatement,annualDepletionIncomeStatement,trailingDepletionIncomeStatement,annualDepreciationAndAmortizationInIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationAndAmortizationInIncomeStatement,annualAmortization,trailingAmortization,annualAmortizationOfIntangiblesIncomeStatement,trailingAmortizationOfIntangiblesIncomeStatement,annualDepreciationIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationIncomeStatement,annualResearchAndDevelopment,trailingResearchAndDevelopment,annualSellingGeneralAndAdministration,trailingSellingGeneralAndAdministration,annualSellingAndMarketingExpense,trailingSellingAndMarketingExpense,annualGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense,trailingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense,annualOtherGandA,trailingOtherGandA,annualInsuranceAndClaims,trailingInsuranceAndClaims,annualRentAndLandingFees,trailingRentAndLandingFees,annualSalariesAndWages,trailingSalariesAndWages,annualGrossProfit,trailingGrossProfit,annualCostOfRevenue,trailingCostOfRevenue,annualTotalRevenue,trailingTotalRevenue,annualExciseTaxes,trailingExciseTaxes,annualOperatingRevenue,trailingOperatingRevenue",
    "merge": "false",
    "period1": "493590046",
    "period2": "1705664498",
    "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com",
}

res = requests.get(link, params=params, headers=headers).json()

all_data = []
for r in res["timeseries"]["result"]:
    type_ = r["meta"]["type"][0]

    if "timestamp" not in r:
        continue

    if type_.startswith("trailing"):
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {"TTM": [r[type_][0]["reportedValue"]["raw"]]},
            index=[type_.replace("trailing", "annual")],
            dtype=float,
        )
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                t: v["reportedValue"]["raw"]
                for t, v in zip_longest(
                    r["timestamp"],
                    (t for t in r[type_] if t),
                    fillvalue={"reportedValue": {"raw": np.nan}},
                )
            },
            index=[type_],
            dtype=float,
        )

    all_data.append(df)

out = (
    pd.concat(all_data)
    .groupby(level=0, as_index=False, group_keys=False)
    .apply(lambda g: g.ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates())
)

out.columns = [
    c if c == "TTM" else pd.to_datetime(c, unit="s").date() for c in out.columns
]
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.2f}".format
print(out[out.columns[::-1]])
```

Prints:

```
                                                                      TTM      2023-09-30      2022-09-30      2021-09-30      2020-09-30
annualBasicAverageShares                                   15744231000.00             NaN  16215963000.00  16701272000.00  17352119000.00
annualBasicEPS                                                       6.16             NaN            6.15            5.67            3.31
annualCostOfRevenue                                       214137000000.00 214137000000.00 223546000000.00 212981000000.00 169559000000.00
annualDilutedAverageShares                                 15812547000.00             NaN  16325819000.00  16864919000.00  17528214000.00
annualDilutedEPS                                                     6.13             NaN            6.11            5.61            3.28
annualDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders                      96995000000.00  96995000000.00  99803000000.00  94680000000.00  57411000000.00
annualEBIT                                                117669000000.00 117669000000.00 122034000000.00 111852000000.00  69964000000.00
annualEBITDA                                              129188000000.00 129188000000.00 133138000000.00 123136000000.00  81020000000.00
annualGrossProfit                                         169148000000.00 169148000000.00 170782000000.00 152836000000.00 104956000000.00
annualInterestExpense                                       3933000000.00   3933000000.00   2931000000.00   2645000000.00   2873000000.00
annualInterestExpenseNonOperating                           3933000000.00   3933000000.00   2931000000.00   2645000000.00   2873000000.00
annualInterestIncome                                        3750000000.00   3750000000.00   2825000000.00   2843000000.00   3763000000.00
annualInterestIncomeNonOperating                            3750000000.00   3750000000.00   2825000000.00   2843000000.00   3763000000.00
annualNetIncome                                            96995000000.00  96995000000.00  99803000000.00  94680000000.00  57411000000.00
annualNetIncomeCommonStockholders                          96995000000.00  96995000000.00  99803000000.00  94680000000.00  57411000000.00
annualNetIncomeContinuousOperations                        96995000000.00  96995000000.00  99803000000.00  94680000000.00  57411000000.00
annualNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation      96995000000.00  96995000000.00  99803000000.00  94680000000.00  57411000000.00
annualNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest  96995000000.00  96995000000.00  99803000000.00  94680000000.00  57411000000.00
annualNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests            96995000000.00  96995000000.00  99803000000.00  94680000000.00  57411000000.00
annualNetInterestIncome                                     -183000000.00   -183000000.00   -106000000.00    198000000.00    890000000.00
annualNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense                  -183000000.00   -183000000.00   -106000000.00    198000000.00    890000000.00
annualNormalizedEBITDA                                    129188000000.00 129188000000.00 133138000000.00 123136000000.00  81020000000.00
annualNormalizedIncome                                     96995000000.00  96995000000.00  99803000000.00  94680000000.00  57411000000.00
annualOperatingExpense                                     54847000000.00  54847000000.00  51345000000.00  43887000000.00  38668000000.00
annualOperatingIncome                                     114301000000.00 114301000000.00 119437000000.00 108949000000.00  66288000000.00
annualOperatingRevenue                                    383285000000.00 383285000000.00 394328000000.00 365817000000.00 274515000000.00
annualOtherIncomeExpense                                    -382000000.00   -382000000.00   -228000000.00     60000000.00    -87000000.00
annualOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses                       -382000000.00   -382000000.00   -228000000.00     60000000.00    -87000000.00
annualPretaxIncome                                        113736000000.00 113736000000.00 119103000000.00 109207000000.00  67091000000.00
annualReconciledCostOfRevenue                             214137000000.00 214137000000.00 223546000000.00 212981000000.00 169559000000.00
annualReconciledDepreciation                               11519000000.00  11519000000.00  11104000000.00  11284000000.00  11056000000.00
annualResearchAndDevelopment                               29915000000.00  29915000000.00  26251000000.00  21914000000.00  18752000000.00
annualSellingGeneralAndAdministration                      24932000000.00  24932000000.00  25094000000.00  21973000000.00  19916000000.00
annualTaxEffectOfUnusualItems                                        0.00            0.00            0.00            0.00            0.00
annualTaxProvision                                         16741000000.00  16741000000.00  19300000000.00  14527000000.00   9680000000.00
annualTaxRateForCalcs                                                0.15            0.15            0.16            0.13            0.14
annualTotalExpenses                                       268984000000.00 268984000000.00 274891000000.00 256868000000.00 208227000000.00
annualTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported                      114301000000.00 114301000000.00 119437000000.00 108949000000.00  66288000000.00
annualTotalRevenue                                        383285000000.00 383285000000.00 394328000000.00 365817000000.00 274515000000.00
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, Could you convert the dataframe logic to list comprehension or something similar? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MITHU u can use `json_output = out.to_json()` or `dict_output = out.to_dict()`

Comment: I've already customized it @Sergey K. Thanks.